# Using A Modified Upload Script From W3Schools Broken?

Tags: php

When Using A Modified Upload Script From W3Schools It Doesn't Work And It Was Proven To Work By StackOverflow Users?!?!?!

Here's The Code, Don't Know Whats Happening!
All It Comes Up With Is.

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 16

Invalid file

change_photo.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    ?>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

upload.php

<style>
.sucess{
color:#088A08;
}
.error{
color:red;
}
</style>

<?php
$file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
// Enter your path to upload file here
if (file_exists("profile_pictures/" .
$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "<div class='error'>"."(".$_FILES["file"]["name"].")".
" already exists. "."</div>";
}
else
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$new_file_name = $my_id;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"profile_pictures/" . $new_file_name);
echo "<div class='sucess'>"."Stored in: " .
"profile_pictures/" . $new_file_name."</div>";
}
}
}
else
{
echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the file name in the HTML part. Change:

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

to

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

Comment: it came up with
Upload: Jerry.png
Type: image/png
Size: 285.4423828125 kB
Temp file: C:\xampp\tmp\phpAE3A.tmp

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 39

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpAE3A.tmp' to 'profile_pictures/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 43
Stored in: profile_pictures/

And Didn't Work :(

Comment: @LeviJohnson the answer is in the error message. Session isn't started, so `$my_id` is empty, so copy fails because the file doesn't get a name.

Comment: "Undefined variable: _SESSION in blah blah blah..." Put `session_start();` at the top of upload.php

Comment: Thanks! @Oberst But Now How Do I Find What Filetype It Is, Cuz It Just Comes Out As A Number File, With No Picture Extension

Comment: I Just Had A Thought Of Something Like This!

$filechanger = "{$_SESSION['user_id']}.{$_FILES['type']}";

Comment: You technically dont need an ext to display the image in HTML. However, you are close... You are on the right track. Change `$new_file_name` to `$my_id.".".$upload_exts;`. Or even better yet, you can change `$my_id` to something more meaningful

Comment: Perfect, Now One Last Thing, When A Photo Has To Be Replaced It Won't Let Me Change It What Do I DO?

Comment: Depends... Is the file you are trying to replace [writeable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)? You made need to [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) the file. If it is writeable, is the name you are attempting to replace it with, the same? If nothing else, you could [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the file and just save the new one.

Comment: I just linked 3 options. Check if the file is writeable (`is_writable(filename)`). If true, make sure the file name is the same. If false, make the file writeable (with `chmod(filename,777)`) (then see "If true")

Comment: Derp! `C:\xampp\htdocs\` totally forgot about that. Haha. Then, file permission really shouldnt be an issue at all.

Comment: is there not a way in php to delete the current photo, then upload the new one?